# Why does the TypeScript Playground give me error in console?

Tags: typescript

I went to the typescript playground, by just running the sample file, I got an error in the console. And the run failed.

[image: Uncaught TypeError: window.i is not a function]

Comment: What is your chrome browser’s version? Try to update it or reinstall it.

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit), I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Orta broke something - He'll probably fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @Gerrit0 that makes sense. thanks. Does this mean no one can use the playground for now? thanks.

Comment: The v1 site is deployed, so it is definitely fixed in one sense. I think I've shipped a fix for this on the other hand. 

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/issues/411 is the issue to follow

Comment: @orta Thanks for the update.

Comment: it works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As @orta pointed out, it's a regression, fixed now.